# Show small number of images in foldergalery

Tags: php, gallery

Im having trouble finding some piece of code for showing me the small number of how many images is in a folder in my website. Im using foldergallery.

I need to show the number above my folders, so one would know how many images are in a folder.

Can someone please point me there or write some kind of PHP code for this.

Thank you

R

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$directory = "/path/to/directory/";

if(is_dir($directory)) {
    $images = glob($directory . "{*.jpg,*.JPG,*.jpeg,*.png,*.PNG,*.gif,*.GIF}");

    $numberOfImages =  count($images);

}
```

After that, you just print the $numberOfImages where you want.

Comment: Hello, thank you. Can you be more specific, please as I'm not a coder, so somehow couldn't make it work. I put the code with <?php...> in my prettyphoto.htt template, changed the path but nothing shows up. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to print the $numberOfImages with echo command . Like this echo $numberOfImages; So somewhere in your html template, probably within <div></div> or <p></p> tags you should ad <?php echo $numbersOfImages; ?>

Comment: I just edited the answer, there was missing slash in the string that representing the directory path.

Comment: Thank you, I did that, but still there is no change. Nothing shows up. I put the echo between <div> added some class even but stil empty. ??

Comment: I have no idea. Probably is problem with the path. You can var_dump($images) inside if block, just to be sure that everything is executed.